# WatchService: passing parameter at registration

Tags: java, java-7, watchservice

I'm looking for a way to pass parameters when registering a Path to a WatchService. The goal is to get those parameters when processing events related to the Path.

```
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
....
path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE); //I would like to pass some parameters here...
....
key = watchService.take(); // ... so that I can get these parameters here from the WatchKey
```

Any idea if it is possible?

Thanks,
Mickael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that the `WatchKey` returned at registration is the same as the one returned by the `take()/poll()` method.

I managed to solve it by maintaining an external `Map<WatchKey, ....>`.